# How to stop all containers with Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible, containers

I am trying to stop all running containers as a first step and then remove them.

I know that I can do it using Anslible shell package and run this command:

```
docker container stop $(docker container ls -aq)
```

As a second step I can do the same with shell package and clean the dead containers / images / volumes:

```
docker system prune -a -f --volumes
```

I have tried something like this (sample of code):

```
- name: Stop all containers:
  shell: "docker container stop $(docker container ls -aq)"
  ignore_errors: yes
```

Unfortunately when containers are 0 this throws an error which I would like to handle.

I could improve it by adding the following:

```
- name: Get info on docker host and list images
  docker_host_info:
    containers: yes
  register: result

- name: Stop all containers
  shell: "docker container stop $(docker container ls -aq)"
  when: result.host_info.Containers != 0
```

I would like to do it with by using purely an Ansible package e.g. ([docker_host_info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_host_info_module.html#examples)). I am able to extract a complex list with containers, that include all the information but I can not found a way to get either the Id or name of the containers.

My plan is to make a loop after with the Ids or names and stop them one by one.

I managed to extract the number of containers (string format), but I can not find a way to convert it to index so I can loop through.

Sample of code:

```
- name: Get info on docker host and list images
  docker_host_info:
    containers: yes
  register: result

- name: Debug dockerInfo
  debug:
    var: result.containers 
    # var: result.host_info.Containers
    # loop: "{{ result.host_info.Containers }}"
    # loop: "{{ range(0, 4)|list }}"
  when: result.host_info.Containers != 0
```

Is it possible to convert the returned string to an index and iterate through this index e.g. (fake sample of code):

```
- name: Debug dockerInfo
  debug:
    var: "{{ result.containers[item].Id }}
  loop: result.host_info.Containers
  when: result.host_info.Containers != 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result.containers` is a list so you can iterate directly on it:

```
- name: Debug dockerInfo
  debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ result.containers }}"
  when: result.containers | length != 0
```

BTW, the `var` of `debug` only takes a variable name, to debug an expression you have to use `msg` instead.
BTW2, for the `loop` keyword you must use the curly braces to evaluate the expression.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was overthinking and I was trying to extract the index from the dictionary for no reason. When a simple loop with the names will do the work. For example: `msg: "{{ item.Names[0] }}"`. Based on this string I can easily stop the containers. Thank you for your time and effort.